# Hide actual URL and display alternate URL using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect user from `localhost/test` --> `localhost/new/test/index.php`
But user should see `localhost/test` in the address bar though the content is fetched from  localhost/new/test

How to achieve this using htaccess. Any help is appreciated.

Existing solutions on hiding actual URL did not work for me. So kindly help to resolve this issue.

Example that we are trying

```
folder level 1 => localhost/test/index.php
folder level 2 => localhost/new/test/index.php
```

User types `localhost/test/index.php` in URL but he should be shown the content of `localhost/new/test/index.php` without displaying `localhost/new/test/index.php`

User should still see the old URL localhost/test/index.php

Comment: Please provide examples what you have tried so far. We can help you to improve them.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called internal or silent redirection without using `R` flag (use for external redirection).

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if URI doesn't start with /new
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new/ [NC]
# redirect to /new/$1
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /new/$1 [L]
```

#### Suggest you to read: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but sorry to say that its not hiding the URL. I could still see localhost/new/test in address bar

Comment: That is only possible if you some other rule or code in your system. Do your have any other rule in your .htaccess OR is there any other .htaccess also in your system?

Comment: No, i have not written any rule in my htaccess other than your suggested one, also i dont have any other htaccess file as well. Kindly let me know if you have tried out this code and if its working as per the requirement.

Comment: I never post an answer before testing it myself :P Are you sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled in your Apache config?